# Is CDATA supposed to be URL-encoded?

Tags: html, android, xml, urlencode, cdata

Obviously the answer is no... right? The reason I ask is because I have this string defined in XML for an Android app:

```
<string name="foo"><![CDATA[<html><body><p>This%20is%20a%20test</p></body></html>]]></string>
```

All I do to the string is read it, and display in an HTML view. I would *not* have expected the `%20`s to be interpreted, yet they are. Is this the correct behaviour, or is Android being typically buggy?

Comment: What are you doing with the string? Just reading it from the DOM certainly should not URL-decode it. If you're passing the string into a query parameter or something, of course...

Comment: Ah found the answer in the documentation (surprisingly!): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html loadData(... String data ...) : "A String of data in the given encoding. The date must be URI-escaped -- '#', '%', '\', '?' should be replaced by %23, %25, %27, %3f respectively".  How utterly bizarre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is CDATA supposed to be URL-encoded?

[No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA). The only rule of CDATA is that it can't contain a closing CDATA `]]>` - everything else is fair game.